# Enumerating Sets of Nodes of an Undirected / unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, enumeration

On an undirected and unweighted graph, how is it possible to enumerate all the groups of connected nodes having a length of 1,2,..,n (n is a user defined value)?

This question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671486/enumerating-all-paths-in-a-tree); with this difference:
for n=3; I also require to find the path: A-B-C and C-E-F.

If n is 4, then the paths should also include:

A-B-C-D

A-B-C-E

A-B-C-F

A-C-E-F

I guess this is a problem of something like; "all pairs - all paths", where each path can contain at most n nodes.
Would you also please tell the methods computational complexity?

My thinking is that I need to use both DFS and BFS simultaneously, but I am not sure whether this is efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use DFS with an extra variable that is passed down the recursion of `length`, which will be reduced at every iteration. The stop condition will be when this extra variable reached 0.

Something along the lines of:

```
DFS(source,length,path):
   print path //this is always done, because we want all paths up to n
   if (length == 0): //stop clause
      return
   for each (source,u) is an edge:
       path.append(u)
       DFS(u,length-1,path)
       path.removeLast() //clean up environment
```

Another (less efficient, but might be more elegant) is doing an [Iterative Deepening DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search), with length=1,2,...,n (and put the print in the stop clause only)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please tell what do you mean by path.removeLast()?

Comment: @user1959766: In here `path` is a list, and `path.removeLast()` removes the last element from it. `path.append(u)` adds `u` to the end of the list

Comment: Thanks. However, I think the problem persists: as the last element is removed, we also lose some of the sets of nodes. In the example given, how is it possible for the group of nodes A-B-C to be detected, if we remove B?

Comment: @user1959766: You don't remove anything, you remove it from the *current* path only, after you have finished exploring it as much as you can. r am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Firstly, I think I wrongly posed the question initially (sorry the inconvenience it caused), better way is: finding the set of connected groups of nodes (rather than paths), where each groups size is <= n. When I trace your pseudo-code for length = 2 (i.e. n=3) in the example I gave, I think the resulting groups of nodes look like this:  - A  - AB  - ABD  - AC  - ACE  - ACF. Please correct me if I am wrong.